# Postgres: Opting in to weaker transaction isolation guarantees for a single table or a single read?

Tags: postgresql

I'm writing a web app with Postgres 13 as the backend.  Most requests are wrapped in a transaction, using the `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level.

For most things, this works great.  However, there are some cases where I'd like some reads in the transaction to have less strict isolation.

For example, I'm introducing a `global_flags` table for infrequently-changed settings that any request might make use of:

```js
await sqlAsync(`BEGIN; SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE`);

const batchSize = await sqlAsync(
    `SELECT value FROM global_flags WHERE name = 'batch_size'`);

// ... a bunch more work ...

await sqlAsync('COMMIT');
```

I'm a bit worried that when we manually make changes to `global_flags` entries, we might cause an increase in "serialization failure" errors for in-flight transactions.  Is there a way to tell Postgres that I don't need as strong of a consistency guarantee for reads of the `global_flags` table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You needn't worry a bit.

If the one transaction does nothing except change that flag, and the other just reads the table (and doesn't try to write to it!), the two transactions will have a simple RW or WR dependency on each other, and there will be no cycles that cause a serialization error.